# External API call from Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to call an External API from a script anytime a specific cell is updated.

Below is the code.

```
function onEdit(e)
{ 
var zone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getAc‌​tiveCell().getA1Nota‌​tion(); 
if ( ((zone=="Z370") || (zone=="Z371") || (zone=="Z372")) && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(zone).getValues()==‌​"WAITING") 
{ 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('ps1w2.rt.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel‌​/public/rt/999S7X/ExecuteTask)‌​; 
} ; 
}
```

The first external API call is working fine but the next are failing because the first is still running.

I am wondering if it is possible to manage a job queue within Google App to avoid the execution failure. The second call should start when the first is completed.

Can you please confirm/suggest.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you share the code ?

Comment: function onEdit(e){
 // var range = e.range;
  var zone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
if  ( ((zone=="Z370") || (zone=="Z371") || (zone=="Z372")) && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(zone).getValues()=="WAITING")
  {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://ps1w2.rt.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/public/rt/999S7X/RunTask);
  }  ;
}

Comment: is that all the code? And it is recommended to post the code in the question itself. It seems incomplete right now and comments field has limited characters for text.

Comment: The code is in the question. As you know the code is using a Google App Script trigger to execute a ReST call when a specific column in the Google SpreadSheet is updated. I hope it helps.